# Phase angle of current in AC circuit

Tags: electricity

Considering an AC circuit with a capacitor. I learnt that the current leads voltage by a phase angle π/2. This means current starts before voltage. But I learnt that current doesn't exist without voltage. So how this is possible? Also can anybody explain the beauty of phase angle in physics?[image: phase angle]

Comment: *"But I learnt that current doesn't exist without voltage"* - Are you thinking of Ohm's law here?  You're studying an *ideal* capacitor, not a resistor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have an simple RC circuit powered by a,say, $12V$.

[image]

Suppose now the capactior is discharged.

When you turn the circuit on, the capacitor voltage never changes instantly( its voltage function is derivative anywhere in the graph Voltage x Time), which can be easily seen when you get the capacitor formula $I=C\frac{dv}{dt}$.

Back to our circuit: when it´s powerered on the capacitor has no charge stored and it can´t change its voltage instantly, so the voltage across it will be $0$ and the current flowing through it at $t=0$ will be $I=\frac{12}{R}$.

So from this you can see the capacitor does not behave like a resistor which always needs a voltage across it to have current flowing and vice-versa.

And finally, to answer your last question: What is the phase angle then?

I don´t know if  you understand what a phasor is like and how to describe it with complex numbers, then I´ll show you a simplified way without phasors. Thus, using only trigonometric functions from $I=C\frac{dv}{dt}$ we now apply a sinusoidal source across the capacitor to see how it behaves.

Thus, let´s suppose our sinusoidal source to be $V=Acos(wt)$. Now we know that $\frac{dv}{dt}=-Awsin(wt)=-Awcos(wt-90º)=Awcos(wt+90º)$.

Now let´s put them together

$V=A*cos(wt)$

$I=CAw*cos(wt+90º)$

We can see the current is leading the voltage by 90º! I hope that will make you understand a little bit of what this leading and lagging is about.

Answer (score 0):

> But I learnt that current doesn't exist without voltage

This is not true in general. For resistors Ohm’s law says that $ V=R I$, so for resistors it is true. But not everything behaves that way. Capacitors, inductors, and superconductors can all have current without voltage.